# UITableViewController: what's with the incomplete method implementation warnings?

Tags: xcode, warnings, uitableview

I'm working on my first iOS/Cocoa Touch app, and to handle user settings, I need to build a few table views for a navigation controller. At any rate, I created a custom UITableViewController, and pushed it on my UINavigationController. I didn't change a thing (except the return numbers) in the following two methods, but they kick out warnings in XCode. What gives?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `#warning` directive, appropriately enough, causes the compiler to emit a warning. Delete those two lines and the warnings should go away.

Comment: Interesting. Why are they there in the first place? Is it something Apple put in to point out you need to alter the return values?

Comment: @Gregir: That's probably exactly what it's for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can't believe I missed the concept of #warning directives in all my reading so far.